# change select value when press button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i'm still Beginner at this
i have table and i select data between two date range using this code and its working fine for me

```
$StartDate = "2016-01-01";
$EndDate =  "2016-12-30";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users where submit_date BETWEEN '$StartDate' AND '$EndDate'") or die(mysql_error());
```

then i added 2 data picker and button

```
echo "<form method=post action=><table>".
"<tr><td>Start Date : </td><td><input type=date name=StartDate value=$StartDate></td></tr>".
"<tr><td>End Date : </td><td><input type=date name=EndDate value=$EndDate></td></tr>".
"<tr><td colspan=2><input type=submit name=UpdateSelect value=Set></td></tr>".
"</table></form>";
```

now i need help with this
how to update the page when i press the sumbit button 
to start selecting from the new start date and end date.

i'm sorry for my bad english. 
and thanks

Comment: **STOP** using depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared statement.

Comment: `action=><table>` huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small demo of your problem hope will help you and solve your problem. I assume you are using mysqli connection object.

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
    {
        $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
        $end_date   = $_POST['end_date'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where submit_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }

    $conn->close();
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="date" name="start_date" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="date" name="end_date" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Set"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <!-- here your data manupulation logic -->
    <?php
        if (isset($result) && !empty($result))
        {
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "id: " . $row["id"];. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The  is used for input fields that should contain a date.
Depending on browser support, a date picker can show up in the input field.

Comment: Thank You :) its working perfect,
 but is there way to make "end date" value showing today date

i'm trying to use $Today =  date('Y-m-d');

///   <td><input type=date name=end_date value=$Today/></td>

but its not working

Comment: value="<?php echo $Today; ?>"

Comment: syntactically your coding style is totally wrong.